# Save Unbound Values in a Form with an Append Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to be able to store the values in a list of controls from a form in a table using an Append query in VBA. Here is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub btnSave()

Dim ctl As Control
Dim str As String
Dim RecordInsertSQL As String
str = Empty

For each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is Textbox or TypeOf ctl is Combobox or TypeOf ctl Is Listbox Then
    Debug.Print ctl.Name
    Else:
    End If
Next ctl

RecordInsertSQL = INSERT INTO tbl_Save ([ctl.Name1], [ctl.Name2]) VALUES ('" & Me.ctl.Name1.Value & "','" & Me.ctl.Name2.Value & "');"

DoCmd.RunSQL RecordInsertSQL
MsgBox("Your data has been saved")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of using VBA to do an insert into a table from controls on a form is to actually name the control and the field that the data is going into, as:

- Dates and strings require wrapping in delimiters (octothorpes and single quotes respectively);
- You may need to handle null values, and convert them to either 0 or a zero-length string;
- If other controls are added to the form, then your code may either stop working, or else the wrong value may get inserted into the field.

Your SQL would therefore look like (assuming both fields are text):

```
RecordInsertSQL="INSERT INTO [tbl_Save] (Field1, Field2) VALUES ('" & cboField1 & "','" & cboField2 & "');"
```

Regards,

Comment: I was able to create a recordset which stored the values in the form into a table. Thanks!!!